# HTTP traffic vs Socket traffic

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, port, portforwarding

I know that in order to connect to a web site, in the TCP layer, the source port is a high random number and the destination is 80. So, the response segment has 80 as source port and that random port number as destination port.

I understand from this that the client listens to that random port number when waiting the response of its HTTP request.

When I make a TCP server socket and I want to make it listen to a specific port(47860), why should I configure my router and forward the port while I don't need to do so when using a web browser? 
What's the difference between HTTP socket and a generic TCP socket?

Comment: HTTP is a application layer protocol which uses TCP. The 'socket' is relevant at the TCP layer and not at application. There is no "HTTP socket"

Comment: You'll have to read up on TCP. Client doesn't listen to anything, the connection is already open. Also there is no such thing as an HTTP socket.

Comment: Under an HTTP-based process, we find a TCP socket; for this reason I used the "HTTP socket" term.

Comment: Why does my router accept an incomming HTTP traffic and block an incomming socket traffic?

Comment: "I understand from this that the client *listens* to that random port number when waiting the response of its HTTP request." I don't want to confuse you, but "listens" is not the correct term here. There are two types of sockets, server sockets and client sockets. We say that server sockets listen for new connections, while client sockets connect to server sockets. The difference is that a server socket is able to exchange traffic with multiple clients, while a client socket can communicate with a single server.

Answer (score 1):

When a client behind NAT initiates traffic to a remote host, the NAT router remembers this. This way, responses from that remote host to the local client can be redirected to the client.

When you have a server behind NAT without its listening port forwarded, any incoming traffic to that port will be dropped by the router: there was no prior traffic from behind the NAT *to* that client, so there's nothing to remember, and nothing to forward as far as the router is concerned.

Comment: Assume that I connect to a website and my random source port number is 35691. The router generates another public source port number (for example 43512). Does the router open this port (43512) to receive the HTTP response?

Comment: I disabled my router firewall, then I checked the ports with canyouseeme.org. The ports still closed. If they are blocked from the ISP, how can my router receive the HTTP responses for example?

Comment: The HTTP part is entirely irrelevant, as is the firewall. The point is: traffic initiated from behind your NAT (such as a browser making an HTTP request) does not need port forwarding (the router does this automatically and temporarily), traffic initiated from outside that needs to be routed to a machine inside (for example you running a web server) _does_ need a permanent port forwarding, because there was no prior traffic.

Comment: I have done port forwarding and disabled the router and the windows firewalls. Also, I configured my web server to a high port number to avoid ISP port blocking problems. I still cannot connect to my web server remotely (no problems from LAN)

Comment: I was under the assumption this was a theoretical question, not a _"Help me make my port forwarding work"_. I will not help with the latter, as it is off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: Theoretically, I have understood what you have explained about NAT. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@CodeCaster's answer is correct, I'll try to give more details.

So we have 2 cases here: 1) web-browser behind NAT 2) web-server behind NAT. The main difference between them is the direction of the first packet.

In (1) web-browser initiate communication and so sends a packet via the router. NAT in the router registers this packet as an entry in a table that maps source IP/port to destination IP/port. When the router receives the reply from the web-server it looks up that entry in NAT table to determine where to forward the packet, and then your web-browser receives the reply.

In (2) NAT in the router has no idea about your web-server existence. A external web-browser sends a request to your web-server using your public IP and so the packet arrives to the router. Now router doesn't know what to do with the packet because neither NAT table nor port forwarding doesn't have port 80 registered. So, in other words, NAT handles outgoing connections automatically and for incoming connections you need to configure port forwarding.

Comment: Thank you very much